# react-select don't show keyboard on mobile devices and prevent zoom

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using React-Select version 2.4.2. Testing on iOS Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

I have gone through the [documentation](https://react-select.com/props) but cannot find the correct prop to pass for this to just happen.

I want the menu to show on mobile, but not the keyboard, or any iOS native footer. 
Toggling the isDisabled doesn't work, of course, since it disables the entire input and select menu.

Flipping the "searchable" prop to false DOES in fact disable the keyboard, BUT shows a footer with "Done" on Safari and Firefox, and an "X" on Chrome.

Ideally, I could just disable the input but still allow for the touch selection of the options.

Example code:

```
    <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        options={selectOptions}
        onChange={handleOptionSelect}
        placeholder={placeholderText}
        isDisabled={false} {/* bool toggles affect entire plugin */}
        blurInputOnSelect={true} {/* don't want any input/keyboard on mobile */}
        readonly={true} {/* tried, didn't work */}
        searchable={false} {/* disables keyboard, but still shows iOS footer with "Done" button in Safari and Firefox, and an "X" in Chrome, and zooms in when touching select element */}
    />
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try `inputProps={{readOnly:true}}` or `isSearchable={ false }`. `readonly` is not exposed as a direct prop on the `<Select />` component.

Comment: Thanks, where did you find documentation on inputProps?

Comment: Still having issues with the zooming in and the native footer with the Done/X button.

Comment: Thanks for digging that up from the bowels of the issues. They should update their docs. Cheers!

Comment: `isSearchable={ false }` is exactly what I needed to disable the keyboard on mobile devices. I'd have preferred to have an option not to open it when focusing the input, but that'll do.

Answer (score 1):

Craig, have you tried setting the font-size of the input to 16px? This prevents zooming on iOS when focusing an input field